# Convert multiple numeric-type columns to single date-type column

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, merge

I have data frame that show different temperature parameter as a function of daily datetime, just like this:

```
| YEAR | DOY | T2M  |  TS   |
| 1991 | 1  | 25.69 | 25.76 |
| 1991 | 2  | 23.12 | 21.46 |
| 1991 | 3  | 21.65 | 22.56 |
| ---- | ---| ----- | ----  |
| 1991 |300 | 21.49 | 22.75 |
| 1991 |301 | 21.49 | 22.75 |
| 1991 |302 | 21.49 | 22.75 |
```

I want to convert YEAR and DOY (Day of Year) columns into single column of datetime in R, with the date format of dd/mm/yyyy

```
|    DATE    | T2M   |  TS   |
| 01/01/1991 | 25.69 | 25.76 |
| 02/01/1991 | 23.12 | 21.46 |
| 03/01/1991 | 23.12 | 21.46 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change each year to the first `Date` of that year, add `DOY` and subtract `1`:

```
dat$DATE <- as.Date(ISOdate(dat$YEAR, 1, 1)) + dat$DOY - 1

dat[c("DATE", "T2M", "TS")]
```

```
        DATE   T2M    TS
1 1991-01-01 25.69 25.76
2 1991-01-02 23.12 21.46
3 1991-01-03 21.65 22.56
4 1991-10-27 21.49 22.75
5 1991-10-28 21.49 22.75
6 1991-10-29 21.49 22.75
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `as.Date` on the pasted string with format `%Y %j`

```
transform(df, date = as.Date(paste(YEAR, DOY), "%Y %j"), YEAR=NULL, DOY=NULL)

   T2M    TS       date
1 25.69 25.76 1991-01-01
2 23.12 21.46 1991-01-02
3 21.65 22.56 1991-01-03
4 21.49 22.75 1991-10-27
5 21.49 22.75 1991-10-28
6 21.49 22.75 1991-10-29
```